# How to remove image from button from code in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have a button, and set image for it. How I can remove that image later if I need?
This peace of code does't works for me:

```
[sender setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: check and see if you have set the buttons image or background Image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sender` needs to be your `UIButton`.

The only place `sender` might be valid is if it's in an `IBAction` called by your button, e.g.:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
   [sender setImage: nil forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

But outside of *that*, you probably need to connect your button to an `IBOutlet` and then you can set the image to nil whenever you wish.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, it right. Sender is UIButton.But this button was created from code not in designer.

Comment: right.. so when you create your button in code, assign it to a object variable (e.g. `UIButton * myButton` in your .h interface file) and then you can replace `sender` up there with `myButton` and set the button's image to nil.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
[sender setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```